# c3js › value 0 aligned between Y and Y2

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

How to align the Y 0 axis value to Y2 0 axis value?

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynz6quum/1/) to understand.

I tried the option `center:0` on the axe's but i don't want 0 on center of graph..

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 2000, 350, 300, -200, -50, 0],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        types: {
            data1: 'line',
            data2: 'bar'
        },
        axes:{
            data1:'y',
          data2:'y2'
        }
    },
    axis: {
        y: {
            padding: {bottom: 0}

        },
         y2: {
                show:true,
            padding: {bottom: 0}

        },
        x: {

            min: 0,
            show: true
        }
    },
    grid: {
        x: {
            show: false
        },
        y: {
            show: false,
            lines: [
                {value: 0.0, text: 'i want 0 here ->', class:'red'}
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

[Official documentation](http://c3js.org/reference.html).

Thanks.

Comment: Is it not as simple as adding a `min: -20` to axis.y2, as in https://jsfiddle.net/ynz6quum/2/ ? Or does that not produce your desired result?

Comment: The error persists when I update, some way to calculate this "min" dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you want the same proportion of the axes ranges above and below zero, which is why min: -20 would work for this particular example

This would work in general after you've generated your chart:

```
var d1 = d3.extent(chart.data.values("data1"));
var d2 = d3.extent(chart.data.values("data2"));
if (d2[0] < 0 || d1[0] < 0) {
        var prop1 = d1[0] < 0 ? -(d1[1] / d1[0]) : Math.Infinity; 
    var prop2 = d2[0] < 0 ? -(d2[1] / d2[0]) : Math.Infinity;
    if (prop1 > prop2) {
        d1[0] = -(d1[1] / prop2);
    } else {
          d2[0] = -(d2[1] / prop1);
    }
    chart.axis.range({
            min: {y: d1[0], y2: d2[0]},
          max: {y: d1[1], y2: d2[1]}
    });
}
```

Basically if either (or both) series has a negative value then it scales both series to have the same proportion of positive to negative range using the min/max axis settings. This means zero sits at the same vertical point for both

https://jsfiddle.net/ynz6quum/4/

Comment: It works perfectly, I am very grateful! Thank you mgraham ;)

Comment: Anyone visiting the jsfiddle - note you need to add a resource URL https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js or similar. JSFiddle seems to have lost the d3 reference in soooo many c3 examples.

Comment: yeah, I've noticed that. The trouble with the jsfiddles is that the c3 master has moved onto versions that only work with d3 v4 and above. You can in the dropdown above the code segment (should say javascript and d3 3.x) to change the d3 version to 4.13.0 under 'frameworks and extensions' and it works.